# JS find function pushing undefined

Tags: javascript

I created a "filter" function that receives an array of objects. Each object has an `accountId` property. My function is supposed to filter out objects that have a different `accountId`. It is, however, pushing an `undefined` object in there.

What's wrong with my function?

```
export const filterItems = (myArray, accountId) => {

   let filteredItems = [];
   filteredItems.push(myArray.find(items => items.accountId === accountId));

   return filteredItems;
}
```

When I pass an `accountId` to my function that is not in the array, the output is an array with one item in it and the item is undefined -- see below:

```
[
  0: undefined
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On a side note: Why does your function return an _Array_, named filteredItem**s**, if you only intent to return one element or none? At least, that's what `Array.prototype.find()` does. Maybe you meant to do `return myArray.filter(...);` ?

Comment: I want to return all elements whose `accountId` matches the one specified in the parameter. So, it may be more than one object in the final result. If none of the objects have a matching `accountId`, I want to return an empty array.

Comment: Then, go for @Nina's answer. That's the only one that will return multiple elements if they match, and an empty array if none does

Comment: Thank you! Could you please tell me why @Nina's solution will return multiple objects? Not sure why the others would only return one object.

Comment: From the [MDN Docs for `find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find): _"The find() method returns the value of the **first element** in the array that satisfies the provided testing function."_. But for [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): _"The filter() method creates a new array with **all elements** that pass the test implemented by the provided function."_

Comment: @Sam it's because of the intrinsic differences between `.find()` and `.filter()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just filter the array and return an empty array if not found.

```
export const filterItems = (myArray, accountId) =>
    myArray.filter(items => items.accountId === accountId);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code always calls .push(). The .find() function returns undefined if the item isn't found.

You can grab the return value from `.find()` and then only push the result when it's actually found:

```
let filteredItems = [];
let item = myArray.find(items => items.accountId === accountId);
if (item !== undefined)
  filteredItems.push(item);
return filteredItems;
```

Answer (score 3):

`myArray.find(items => items.accountId === accountId)` is returning `undefined` (and it is being pushed to `filteredItems`)

Try this instead:

```
//...
let item = myArray.find(items => items.accountId === accountId);

if(item) {
    filteredItems.push(item);
}
//...
```